# Build API service with URL query, 20 data item per page (codeigniter PHP)

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I want to build API service for my images folder (directory) with features:

1. But I want use url query to show 20 images URL per page.
2. And reverse sorting.

*example:*

**I have this images on my directory**

1. /images/path.jpg
2. /images/path1.jpg
3. /images/path2.jpg
4. /images/path3.jpg
5. /images/path4.jpg
6. /images/path5.jpg
7. /images/path6.jpg
8. /images/path7.jpg
9. /images/path8.jpg
   10./images/path9.jpg
10. /images/path10.jpg
11. /images/path11.jpg
12. /images/path12.jpg
13. /images/path13.jpg
14. /images/path14.jpg
15. /images/path15.jpg
16. /images/path16.jpg
17. /images/path17.jpg
18. /images/path18.jpg
19. /images/path19.jpg
20. /images/path20.jpg
21. /images/path21.jpg
22. /images/path22.jpg
23. /images/path23.jpg
24. /images/path24.jpg
25. /images/path25.jpg
26. /images/path26.jpg
27. /images/path27.jpg
28. /images/path28.jpg
29. /images/path29.jpg
30. /images/path30.jpg
31. /images/path31.jpg
32. /images/path32.jpg
33. /images/path33.jpg
34. /images/path34.jpg
35. /images/path35.jpg
36. /images/path36.jpg
37. /images/path37.jpg
38. /images/path38.jpg
39. /images/path39.jpg
40. /images/path40.jpg
41. /images/path41.jpg

**I want the API url and data item look like this**

*mypage.com/images-json?page=1*

```
{
"img1": "/images/path41.jpg",
"img2": "/images/path40.jpg",
"img3": "/images/path39.jpg",
"img4": "/images/path38.jpg",
"img5": "/images/path37.jpg",
"img6": "/images/path36.jpg",
"img7": "/images/path35.jpg",
"img8": "/images/path34.jpg",
"img9": "/images/path33.jpg",
"img10": "/images/path32.jpg",
"img11": "/images/path31.jpg",
"img12": "/images/path30.jpg",
"img13": "/images/path29.jpg",
"img14": "/images/path28.jpg",
"img15": "/images/path27.jpg",
"img16": "/images/path26.jpg",
"img17": "/images/path25.jpg",
"img18": "/images/path24.jpg",
"img19": "/images/path23.jpg",
"img20": "/images/path22.jpg"
}
```

*mypage.com/images-json?page=2*

```
{
"img1": "/images/path21.jpg",
"img2": "/images/path20.jpg",
"img3": "/images/path19.jpg",
"img4": "/images/path18.jpg",
"img5": "/images/path17.jpg",
"img6": "/images/path16.jpg",
"img7": "/images/path15.jpg",
"img8": "/images/path14.jpg",
"img9": "/images/path13.jpg",
"img10": "/images/path12.jpg",
"img11": "/images/path11.jpg",
"img12": "/images/path10.jpg",
"img13": "/images/path9.jpg",
"img14": "/images/path8.jpg",
"img15": "/images/path7.jpg",
"img16": "/images/path6.jpg",
"img17": "/images/path5.jpg",
"img18": "/images/path4.jpg",
"img19": "/images/path3.jpg",
"img20": "/images/path2.jpg"
}
```

*mypage.com/images-json?page=3*

```
{
"img1": "/images/path1.jpg",
"img2": "/images/path.jpg"
}
```

Currently I only have this code, but this code only will show all of images from my directory folder, sorting also not reverse:

```
<?php 
$this->load->helper('directory'); //load directory helper
$dir = "images"; // Your Path to folder
$map = directory_map($dir); /* This function reads the directory path specified in the first parameter and builds an array representation of it and all its contained files. */

foreach ($map as $k)
{?>
     <img src="<?php echo base_url($dir)."/".$k;?>" alt="">

<?php }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use FC_PATH for Directory Url , because base_url is not worked for directory data.so try it hope it will helps you .

```
<?php 
     $this->load->helper('directory'); //load directory helper
     $dir = FCPATH."images/"; // Your Path to folder
     $map = directory_map($dir); /* This function reads the directory path specified in the first parameter and builds an array representation of it and all its contained files. */
     //and for sorting may be use krsort for this .
     krsort($map);

     foreach ($map as $k)
     {?>
        <img src="<?php echo $dir.$k;?>" alt="">

    <?php }
?>
```